# What is the meaning of noise in a dataset with no dependant variable?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, signal-processing, scipy, noise

My understanding of noise & signal comes from the context of bias-variance tradeoff in supervised methods.

But given a dataset with no dependant variable, how do you define noise? & how do you decompose data into signal and noise? ( there used to be the function  `stats.signaltonoise` in scipy which would return ratio of mean/standard_deviation given an array of numbers. What is the rationale behind this?)

Comment: The concept of "dependent variable" is part of a *model:* it is not a property of any dataset.

Comment: I understand that. Proabably my question wasn't phrased well. One of the naive defintions I found was "signal is something that is relevant & noise is anything that is irrelevant". When you have a specific objective (like a dependent variable) its easy to define what features/ what pattern in the data is relevant & irrelevant. But how would you do the same with just a vector of numbers? (for example, the numerical value obtained from scipy's stats.signaltonoise)

Comment: Statisticians, and statistical theory generally, do not characterize signal and noise that way.  The "noise" is an explicit part of a statistical model.  Different models for the same data may have different amounts and kinds of "noise" components.  The decomposition of data into signal and noise also depends on the procedure one uses to fit the model to the data.

Answer (score 1):

Noise is relative to the model.

The term noise doesn't really make sense without a dependent variable.  The signal in a matrix of independent measurements is the information that is useful in predicting the dependent variable; the rest is noise (residual). The same independent dataset may be useful in predicting different dependent variables, or the same dependent variable with different equations, where noise is different for each model.

Even in the colloquial sense, where noise is like the static degrading your TV signal, both the TV show and the noise still have a source you may care about (caring is equivalent to defining your dependent variable). If you're trying to measure cosmic background radiation in the universe, rather than watch TV, whatever that damned television broadcaster is pumping out is noise (or, perhaps a removable confound).

For that reason, @whuber is correct in the comments to the question, that noise is defined as the residual variance not related to the dependent variable(s). Without a dependent variable, it's all noise.